How to avoid having the dimension of predictions and test_dates differetn in a random forest model?
I am new to building and training a model with this complexity. I have found a tutorial on the internet with an example and I follwoed it to adapt the code to the data I work in, but it turned that I may did something wrong somewhere...
The predictions and test_dates to plot the predictions and the true values in a graph do not have the same dimensions an I have this error while trying to executing the code :
Here is the code i used : features being the data frame of the data i read from a csv :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn

#Read in data and display 5 rows
features = pd.read_csv('Datasets for random forest ML/Data_set_Construct2.csv', encoding = 'ANSI', sep =';')
df = features
features.head(5)
#print('The shape of our features is:', features.shape)

features.describe()
from datetime import datetime

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(16, 8))
fig.suptitle('Visual Inspection of the Data', size=20)
seaborn.lineplot(data=features, x='Creation date', y='Quality', ax=axs[0])
axs[0].set(title='Lineplot over Time')
seaborn.boxplot(features['Quality'], orient='h', ax=axs[1])
axs[1].set(title='Boxplot of Z-Axis')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
features.dtypes
#display a part of the new df 
#features.iloc[:,5:].head(5)
features.fillna(value=0)features = pd.get_dummies(features)
#display a part of the new features : 
features.iloc[:,5:].head(100)# Labels are the values we want to predict
labels = np.array(features['Quality'])
# Remove the labels from the features
# axis 1 refers to the columns
features= features.drop('Quality', axis = 1)
# Saving features names for later use
features_list = list(features.columns)
# Convert to numpy array
features = np.array(features)# Using Skicit-learn to split data into training and testing sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Split the data into training and testing sets for FEATURES and LABELS
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
        #Checking the shape of trainig and test data :
print('Training Features Shape:', train_features.shape)
print('Training Labels Shape:', train_labels.shape)
print('Testing Features Shape:', test_features.shape)
print('Testing Labels Shape:', test_labels.shape) # The baseline predictions are the historical averages
baseline_preds = test_features[:, features_list.index('Average_Quality')]
# Baseline errors, and display average baseline error
baseline_errors = abs(baseline_preds - test_labels)
print('Average baseline error: ', round(np.mean(baseline_errors), 2))# Import the model we are using
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
# Instantiate model with 1000 decision trees
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 42)
# Train the model on training data
rf.fit(train_features, train_labels);# Use the forest's predict method on the test data
predictions = rf.predict(test_features)
# Calculate the absolute errors
errors = abs(predictions - test_labels)
# Print out the mean absolute error (mae)
print('Mean Absolute Error:', round(np.mean(errors), 2), 'degrees.')# Calculate mean absolute percentage error (MAPE)
mape = 100 * (errors / test_labels)
# Calculate and display accuracy
accuracy = 100 - np.mean(mape)
print('Accuracy:', round(accuracy, 2), '%.')# Get numerical feature importances
importances = list(rf.feature_importances_)
# List of tuples with variable and importance
feature_importances = [(feature, round(importance, 2)) for feature, importance in zip(features_list, importances)]
# Sort the feature importances by most important first
feature_importances = sorted(feature_importances, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
# Print out the feature and importances 
[print('Variable: {:20} Importance: {}'.format(*pair)) for pair in feature_importances];# New random forest with only the two most important variables
rf_most_important = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators= 1000, random_state=42)
# Extract the two most important features
important_indices = [features_list.index('Index'), features_list.index('Average_Quality')]
train_important = train_features[:, important_indices]
test_important = test_features[:, important_indices]
# Train the random forest
rf_most_important.fit(train_important, train_labels)
# Make predictions and determine the error
predictions = rf_most_important.predict(test_important)
errors = abs(predictions - test_labels)
# Display the performance metrics
print('Mean Absolute Error:', round(np.mean(errors), 2), 'degrees.')
mape = np.mean(100 * (errors / test_labels))
accuracy = 100 - mape
print('Accuracy:', round(accuracy, 2), '%.')
test_important.shapeimport datetime
#transforming the str data of resoluition date to datetime format
df['Resolution date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Resolution date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['Resolution date']
#Extracting the day of the resolution date
df['Day'] = df['Resolution date'].dt.day
days = df['Day']
days
#Extracting the month of the resolution date
df['Month'] = df['Resolution date'].dt.month
months = df['Month']
months
#Extracting the year of the resolution date
df['Year'] = df['Resolution date'].dt.year
years = df['Year']
years
#month
# List and then convert to datetime object
dates = [str(int(year)) + '-' + str(int(month)) + '-' + str(int(day)) for year, month, day in zip(years, months, days)]
dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') for date in dates]# Dataframe with true values and dates
true_data = pd.DataFrame(data = {'date': dates, 'Quality': labels})
# Dates of predictions (skipped)
# Column of dates
test_dates = [str(int(year)) + '-' + str(int(month)) + '-' + str(int(day)) for year, month, day in zip(years, months, days)]# Convert to datetime objects
test_dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') for date in test_dates]# Dataframe with predictions and dates
predictions_data = pd.DataFrame(data = {'date': test_dates, 'prediction': predictions})

here is where i got the error attached
The data has a length of 290 when I tried to see the lentgh here is what I got ;
lentgh of predictions : 73
lentgh of test_dates : 290*
Many thanks in advance for your help
